# customize registration form in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am, newbie on Laravel 5, I need to customize registration form in laraverl 5 so i added some extra fields such as fullname, company, country and mobile number.

I added them successfully to resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
see image:
[image]

and updated Services/Register.php file to save new fields to users table and that's work fine.

my problem now is: i need country field is selected list not textfield.

I have table in database 'countries' and I have model 'Country', so how can it build selected list and fill it with countries from countries table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add:

```
{!! Form::select('country', App\Country::lists('name', 'id'), null, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
```

This will list all the countries to select tag from the database table.

Replace `name` to column name assigned for country name.

> Note: install `"illuminate/html"` package to use Form facade.

**EDIT**: the previous code was a little wrong and it caused errors. Now it is fixed.

Comment: I got this error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: it seems not added by default in laravel 5, so i added form and html provider and it works

Comment: {!! Form::select('country', App\Country::lists('name', 'id'), null, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is missing a 2nd `:`

It should be:

```
{!! Form::select('user_type_id', App\UserType::lists('name', 'id'), null, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
```